# two shared_ptr from same enable_shared_from_this instance

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, reference-counting, weak-ptr, enable-shared-from-this

Given this class which is *enable_shared_from_this*:

```
class connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<connection>
{
   //...
};
```

Suppose I create two instances of `std::shared_ptr` from the *same* `connection*` as follows:

```
std::shared_ptr<connection> rc(new connection);

std::shared_ptr<connection> fc(rc.get(), [](connection const * c) {
                                   std::cout << "fake delete" << std::endl;
                               });
```

So far its good, as  the resource { `connection*` } is owned by a *single* `shared_ptr` — `rc` to be precise, and `fc` just have a fake deleter.

After that, I do this:

```
auto sc = fc->shared_from_this();
//OR auto sc = rc->shared_from_this(); //does not make any difference!
```

Now which `shared_ptr` — `rc` or `fc` — would `sc`  share its *reference-count* with? In other words,

```
std::cout << rc->use_count() << std::endl;
std::cout << fc->use_count() << std::endl;
```

What should these print? I tested this code and [found](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4b580257fb65b85) `rc` seems to have `2` references while `fc` just `1`.

My question is, why is that? and what should be the *correct* behavior and its *rationale*?

**I'm using C++11 and GCC 4.7.3**.

Comment: `fc` knows nothing about `rc` as it is constructed with a raw pointer as if it were a new object.

Comment: @jtbandes - In general. When inheriting from `enable_shared_from_this` it can know more.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the link to the spec :)

Comment: A fake owning smart ptr (non owning "owning" smart ptr) is very problematic. I can see how it might be used for object whose lifetime is eternal (not limited to static objects w/o a dtor), but in general it's a violation of contract if keeping a copy of a smart ptr doesn't extend the lifetime of the object "owned".

Comment: @curiousguy: Well, the idea of "fake" resource-owning smart ptr could be good in certain scenario. Imagine an object pool which creates/destroys/manages objects, and when clients ask it for objects, it gives by wrapping the objects in `std::shared_ptr` in such a way that when the shared_ptr goes out of scope, the object held by it returns to the pool (i.e becomes *available* to be used again).... [Contd].

Comment: [Contd] .. In other words, the smart pointer does **not** have to own the *memory* where the object is created, it may own only the *scope* or a *certain lifetime* during which it's in *acquired* state and once it goes out of scope, the object's state changes to *released*.

Comment: @Nawaz A plausible use case indeed where (1) the deleter is *not* a NOP (2) you have exactly one set of aliased `shared_ptr` for one object

Comment: Exactly... I've implemented `object_pool` *internally* uses `std::unique_ptr` to manage the *memory* and before giving objects to the clients, it wraps the objects in `std::shared_ptr` to enable *automatic* returning to the pool when it gets out of the scope.

Answer (score 1):

> The raw pointer overloads assume ownership of the pointed-to object. Therefore, constructing a shared_ptr using the raw pointer overload for an object that is already managed by a shared_ptr, such as by `shared_ptr(ptr.get())` is likely to lead to undefined behavior, even if the object is of a type derived from `std::enable_shared_from_this`.
>   -- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

In your case you get to shared pointers that have two different ownership information blocks but always increment the ref count of the first shared pointer instance of the class.

If you remove the 'fake deleter' you'l get a double free problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### **On C++11 (and more generally, before C++17)**

the only thing we know is that:

> **[util.smartptr.enab]** shared_from_this();:
>
> *Requires:* enable_shared_from_this shall be an accessible base class of T. *this shall be a subobject of an object t of type T. **There shall be at least one shared_ptr instance p that owns &t.**
>
> *Returns:* A shared_ptr object r that shares ownership with p.
>
> *Postconditions:* r.get() == this.

that if read literally, **implies that it's unspecified if fc->shared_from_this() returns a copy of `rc` or `fc`** (although sane implementations will simply assign to the internal weak_ptr once, hence the behaviour should be the same as in the c++17 case, as you observed).

---

#### **From C++17 on**

the situation is clear: `enable_shared_from_this` is essentially a `weak_ptr` that gets assigned by the first `shared_ptr` constructor (or `make_shared` factory) that sees it's in an expired state.

Hence, `rc` sets the `weak_ptr`, `fc` doesn't, `fc->shared_from_this()` returns a copy of `rc`. `fc.get()` will return a zombie pointer as soon as all `rc` copies get destroyed. **Your observed behaviour is the right one**.

Note that all shared_ptr constructors taking a non null pointer (and at most a deleter and/or an allocator) will own the pointer and manage its lifetime, as if it were constructed anew, the only difference being that only the first one will assign to enable_shared_from_this's weak_ptr, if any.